# offsetLeft value does not include border-left-width on changing offsetParent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I'm testing on.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testDiv.offsetLeft;
}
function myFunction2() {
  var testDiv = document.getElementById("test2");
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = testDiv.offsetLeft;
}
```

```css
#test, #test2 {
  left: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black
}
body {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left: 30px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div id="test">
    <p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </p>
    <p>offsetLeft is: <span id="demo"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="padding-left: 30px; border: 1px solid red; position: relative;">
  <div id="test2">
    <p>
      <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
    </p>
    <p>offsetLeft is: <span id="demo2"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `offsetLeft` value with this counts as `158px`, or adds Body `2px` border-width in it.

---

But if I apply the `position` property to the parent `div` of `div#test` then `offsetValue` counts as `140px`, or it does **not** add `1px` border-width of that parent div.

Why it happens so, can anyone explain please?